# CSS3 Shadow Directions

Tags: css

Can't seem to figure this one out.

This one goes top-right. I need it to go bottom-left.

```
box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 3px #333;
-moz-box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 3px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow: -3px -3px 0 3px #333;
```

There needs to be some type reference book for this. I Googled for about an hour and came up with no results.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but it's best practice to put standard properties last (`box-shadow`) and vendor-specific ones first (`-moz-box-shadow`). This way, standard properties will be used if available. By the way what were your Google search terms that took you an hour to *not* find reference for this property? My [results for "box shadow"](https://www.google.com/search?q=box+shadow) bring up plenty of pages that could answer this.

Comment: Isn't a `-3` an enough sign to try to change to `3` ? A little homework.

Comment: I'll take note of that. Madmartigan. But I searched around and found css3.info. I tried it but I trouble shot a few times to make it work, only to reload the page and see no shadow at all.

Comment: Well there's a big difference between "no results" and simply not understanding the information. Next time, be sure to include what you've tried, or people are just going to give you links to *their* Google results. Also, get friendly with http://jsfiddle.com for running test cases and troubleshooting - very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first parameter is x(+ is right - is left) second is y(+ is down - is up), third is blur and forth is strengh.
do something like this for bottom-left:

```
box-shadow: -3px 3px 0 3px #333;
```

Answer (score 4):

It took me 3 seconds and the term 'css3 shadow' and I found [this](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) ;)

```
 div.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: -3px 3px 0 3px #333;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -3px 3px 0 3px #333;
    box-shadow: -3px 3px 0 3px #333;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a CSS3 editor. Here you can create box shadows (and other sweet CSS3 stuff) in a very WYSIWYG way. Maybe that would help you understand how it works as well?

http://www.css3maker.com/box-shadow.html